# What is the phrase to use about reaching a topic while talking?

Tags: phrases

What is the phrase to use when you want to say that while talking we reached the topic blabla?
Can we say: while talking we came to talk about about blabla?

Comment: ***[touch on something]***?  to mention something when you are talking or writing - 
*He did not touch on the issue of immigration.* - https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/touch-on

Comment: Thank you, but still not sure if there is another proper phrase to be used.

Comment: "...It (blahblah) [_came up_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-up) in conversation"

Comment: I think you need to get to the point.

Comment: Arrived at the subject

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you might you be looking for,

## Come up

> : (of an issue, situation, or problem) occur or present itself, especially unexpectedly.

Some example sentences -

‘*This issue just keeps coming up again and again.*’

---

‘*I'm not even sure that I'd vote on the issue if it were coming up for legalization in my state; there are a lot more pressing economic issues on my mind.*’

---

‘*‘Ninety-seven percent of issues that are coming up are localized,’ he said.*’

---

‘*It's an old thread, but the same issues seem to keep coming up.*’

---

‘*He says the one issue which kept coming up on the doorsteps in the recent General Election campaign was the state of the country's health service.*’

([From Oxford](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/come))

---

**EDIT**

[Cascabel](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509909/what-is-the-phrase-to-use-about-reaching-a-topic-while-talking#comment1236352_509909) has provided a simpler definition of "*come up*"-

> : to be mentioned or talked about in conversation.

([From Cambrigde Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-up))